# “That these ... makes” – why “makes” and what is the role of “that”?

Tags: grammar, word-order, dependent-clause, that

I have the following sentence:

> That these skills are transferable **makes** them especially beneficial.

My question is “simple”: Why *makes?* (Of course, because of *that*.) But, does *that* mean something – *the fact?*  Can we put *that* in other places in this sentence?

Comment: Yes, in this case read "that" as "the fact that".

Comment: @JohnFeltz , I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Only if you split the sentence in two: "These skills are transferable. That makes them especially beneficial." or join them with "and" as "These skills are transferable and that makes them especially beneficial." But it degrades the expressive skills of the speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s first distentangle that sentence:

- *That these skills are transferable* is a [noun clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause#Noun_clause) and the subject of the main sentence.
- *makes* is the verb.
- *them* refers to *these skills* and is the object.
- *especially beneficial* is an [predicative adjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression) referring to *them.*

Now to your questions:

> Why *makes?* (Of course, because of *that*.)

Actually, it’s not because of *that* – at least not in the way you probably think it is. *That* is a conjunction marking the beginning of a noun clause. That *that* is identical to a pronoun is the nature of the English language is something that you have to live with. There are languages related to English that allow for analogous structures but have a distinct word for this purpose (e.g., German has *dass*).

That *makes* has a singular *s* is plainly due to the fact that noun clauses are treated as singular by the English grammar.

> But, does *that* mean something – *the fact?*

*That* is a conjunction and has a grammatical function here, i.e., it informs the reader about the grammatical structure of the sentence. It has no real meaning of its own, e.g., it could not be easily translated to an arbitrary other language (though analogues exist in other languages with a similar grammar, e.g., the German *dass*).

That being said, you can replace *that* with *the fact that, the circumstance that, the concept that,* or something similar in such a situation to approximate the meaning of the sentence or as a help to understand it. Note, however, that neither of these choices is accurate in every context, e.g., the noun clause does not need to describe a fact.

> Can we put *that* in other places in this sentence?

No. English grammar demands that conjunctions are located at the beginning of dependent clauses. You may not even move the noun clause (at least without further modifications) as it is the subject and these have to be at the beginning of a sentence. What you can do is using *it* as a “placeholder” ([expletive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_expletive)) for the noun clause and move it to the end of the sentence:

> It makes these skills especially beneficial that they are transferable.

Note that this shifts the emphasis of the sentence.

Answer (score -3):

'That' is the subject in your sentence. Changing its place is not possible without altering its semantic structure.

In the perspective of:

> That these skills are transferable makes them especially beneficial.

as a sentence, if you were to dispense of `that` you'd obtain:

> These skills are transferable makes them especially beneficial,

**which does not parse.**

On the other hand, omitting `these skills are transferable` **parses** the following sentence:

> That makes them especially beneficial.

Therefore, **that** is indispensable in the particular layout of this sentence. You could move **that** around, but moving the subject to become an object in any sentence will require the transformation from a transitive verbal form as well.

**Also, the subject always conjugates the verb, or the verb is always
conjugated by the subject, either way, that makeS a big difference, and is an important clue, when searching to identify the subject in this sentence. I personally ( as it seems so)  consider conjugation, when it is available, to constitute irrefutable evidence.  When the INDISPENSABLE word that conjugates ( NO! STOP! A COMMON MISTAKE IS TO USE 'THAT' INSTEAD OF USING A GERUNDIVE) *conjugating* the verb is identified, it becomes the only sun the rest of my sentence orbits around.**

Comment: How does " This does not provide an answer to the question" provides an answer to anything either?

Comment: THAT IS THE SUBJECT IN THIS SENTENCE ABOVE, JUST LIKE THIS IS THE SUBJECT IN YOUR SENTENCE. THIS AN THAT ARE CRUCIAL ELEMENTS WHEN USED IN ANY SENTENCE. THEY ARE ALWAYS INDISPENSABLE SUBJECTS PRONOUNS WHEN THEY ARE NOT USE AS DEMONSTRATIVE ARTICLES.

Comment: I KNOW CONCEPTIVELY THAT'S UNIQUE GRAMMATICAL FUNCTION IS TOUGH TO UNDERSTAND TO MOST ENGLISH NATIVE SPEAKERS

Comment: This answer *is* an answer to the question. I disagree with the answer, but it's an answer. "That" is not the subject of the sentence. The subject of the sentence is the entire that-clause: "that these skills are transferable".

Comment: May I suggest you avoid ALL-CAPS, because it gives the impression you are shouting.

Comment: Sorry to be, apparently, so passionate about this.

Comment: 'That' could replace 'these skills are transferable' which can be entirely omitted, and still parse, but not vice-versa, as 'that' is indispensable. Therefore, I see a compound subject here instead, because of this uneven relationship between the dispensable components introducing the verb in this sentence, and the one which conjugates it.